# Excel - iterate and group count if less than 5 reports to manager

Tags: excel, grouping

In Excel given a data set of employees and managers such as

```
Staff Name              Manager
Employee 1              Adam Francis
Employee 2              Adam Francis
Employee 3              Adam Francis
Employee 4              Adam Francis
Employee 5              Adam Francis
Employee 6              Adam Francis
Employee 7              Adam Francis
Employee 8              Adam Francis
Employee 9              Adam Francis
Employee 10             Adam Francis
Employee 11             Adam Francis
Employee 12             Adam Francis
Employee 13             Adam Francis
Employee 14             Adam Francis
Employee 15             Adam Francis
Employee 16             Alexander Hammersley
Employee 17             Alexander Hammersley
Employee 18             Alexander Hammersley
Alexander Hammersley    Caulton Rose
Caulton Rose            Bob Fisher
Adam Francis            Bob Fisher
Employee 21             Mary Bond
Employee 22             Mary Bond
Employee 23             Mary Bond
Employee 24             Mary Bond
Employee 25             Mary Bond
Employee 26             Mary Bond
Mary Bond               Bob Fisher
```

How to rollup the data such that if reporting staff count <5 rollup to the next line manager, once 5 is reached it should not longer rollup?

Such that the above would output

```
Manager       Staff Count
Adam Francis  15
Mary Bond     6
Bob Fisher    7
```

Where Bob has all of Alex, Caulton and their staff but also Adam (as Adam doesn't report to himself!) and Mary

Something along the lines of the following psuedologic.

```
Loop until finished {
If Parent.Children >=5 then GrandParent has only Parent as report && Parent named as result with child count.
elseIf Parent.Children <5 GrandParent = Parent.children + Parent  
Grandparent = Parent
Parent = Child
```

}

Comment: why does mary bond not have 6 in staff count?

Comment: she does now I've corrected it (was a typo on my part)

Comment: What would happen, if Caulton Rose had another 2 employees under her? She would then have 6 and would be written into output. What happens then to Bob Fisher? He would not be accounted for in output at all.

Comment: In that case Bob (being top of the tree) would get the remainder even if less than 5

Comment: And what should the searching order be? Let's imagine, that Bob were higher in the list than Caulton, and that Caulton again had 2 more direct employees. If the code were to go from top to bottom, this time Bob would be written into output with 9, and Caulton with nothing. Different order would however result in Caulton 6, Bob 3.

Comment: The data order is listed in should make no bearing on the result, It collate/group search from logical 'bottom' organisation level (those who are not managers themselves should be grouped into the managers). I thought there was enough data to determine this, (given that Bob is Caulton's Manager, Caulton is subordinate to Bob) The fact that Caulton may or may not be listed above Bob in the data itself should make have no bearing.